# Perl : "Use of uninitialized value" though values are initialized

Tags: perl, shell, initialization, perl-module

Perl is reporing warnings though I have properly initialized all the variables at the start.
Here is my code to generate random unicast mac-address :

```
our $OCTATE_MAX = 255; #Max value stored in 8-bit field
our $octate1 = 0;
our $octate2 = 0;
our $octate3 = 0;
our $umac_serial = "";
sub get_umac_serial
{
    # Can not use sprintf as there is an issue with Igloo-JT
    #return "00:" . sprintf ("\00", int(rand(100))) . ":" . sprintf("\00",int(rand(100)));
     my $first = int(rand(99));
     my $second = int(rand(99));

     return "00:" . "$first" . ":" . "$second";
}
sub get_umac_address
{
    $octate1 = $octate1 + 1;
    $octate1 = int(rand(99));
    $octate2 = int(rand(99));
    $octate3 = int(rand(99));
    if ($octate1 >= $OCTATE_MAX)
    {
        $octate2 = $octate2 + 1;
        $octate1 = 0;
    }
    elsif ($octate2 >= $OCTATE_MAX)
    {
        $octate1 = 0;
        $octate2 = 0;
        $octate3 = $octate3 + 1;
    }
    elsif ($octate3 >= $OCTATE_MAX)
    {
        $umac_serial = get_umac_serial();
        print("Unicast mac-serial # $umac_serial\n");
        $octate1 = 0;
        $octate2 = 0;
        $octate3 = 0;
    }
    $umac_serial = get_umac_serial();
    #my $mac_addr = $umac_serial . ":" . sprintf("\00", $octate3) . ":" . sprintf("\00", $octate2) . ":" . sprintf("\00",$octate1);

    my $mac_addr = $umac_serial . ":" . "$octate3" . ":" . "$octate2" . ":" . "$octate1";

    print("MAC ADDR - $mac_addr\n");
    return $mac_addr;
}
return $result;
#exit;
}   ####### End of mac_addr
```

Though values are properly initialized, perl throws the below error :

```
Jul 29 01:14:25 [WARN ] perl: Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at /var/lib/igloo_jt/explorer/2015/7/1251/mac_addr.pm line 77. Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at /var/lib/igloo_jt/explorer/2015/7/1251/mac_addr.pm line 77. 
Jul 29 01:14:25 [WARN ] perl: Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at /var/lib/igloo_jt/explorer/2015/7/1251/mac_addr.pm line 81. Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at /var/lib/igloo_jt/explorer/2015/7/1251/mac_addr.pm line 81. MAC ADDR - 00:74:53:58:33:0 
Jul 29 01:14:25 [WARN ] perl: Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at /var/lib/igloo_jt/explorer/2015/7/1251/mac_addr.pm line 81. Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at /var/lib/igloo_jt/explorer/2015/7/1251/mac_addr.pm line 81. 
MAC ADDR - 00:51:68:64:69:0
```

Whats wrong with this code ?

Comment: Show your real code. What you pasted doesn't have 77 lines.

Comment: Which line is line 77? Look there. Also: `use strict;` `use warnings;` You may want to reframe the question though - it _looks_ like what you're trying to do is generate random MAC addresses, and that's way easier than this.

Comment: Also note that "use of uninitialized value" just means the value is `undef`. It doesn't mean a variable was never assigned to.

Comment: You might be interested to know that `$octate1++` does not trigger the undefined warning that `$octate1 = $octate1 + 1` does, when the variable is `undef`.

Comment: Also, why do you assign that to `$octate1` when you overwrite the value on the next line? `"00:" . "$first" . ":" . "$second"` is painful. It should be written `"00:$first:$second"`, or better yet `join ":", "00", $first, $second`

Comment: @TLP  Rest of code is comment and use module code. $octate1 is initialized to 0 at the start. How can it be undef ? Also I am overwriting the value as it was throwing warning at ` $octat1 = $octate1 + 1 ` . I forgot to comment this line

Comment: @AnilKumarKK "How can it be undef ?" - To answer that question, you need to **show your real code** in full.

Comment: I find the presence of a trailing additional `return` line rather suspicious.

Comment: @AnilKumarKK "How can it be undef?" Well, irregardless of what is possible or not, the fact of the matter is that it *is* clearly undef. Most likely as a result of your using global variables, it has been altered somewhere, somehow. It does not really matter that you initialize it at the top of your module, if that module is called from another program, it can be altered. Subroutines are defined at compile time, and does not really follow the program flow.

Answer (score 1):

I bet that in the top of the program, the part you didn't display in your question, your main program code is calling one or more of those subroutines.

When you declare a variable with `my` or `our`, the initialization does not happen at compile-time.  It only happens when normal program flow gets to the statement.

If my hunch is right, you can fix this problem by either moving the declaration to the top of your program, before any calls to functions that use the variables.  Or you can write explicit compile-time initialization like this:

```
our $octate1;
our $octate2;
our $octate3;
BEGIN
{
    $octate1 = $octate2 = $octate3 = 0;
}
```

Comment: `our $octate1 = 0;` Doesn't this initialize the variable to 0 ?

Comment: Initialize, no.  It does assign the 0 to the variable, but only when the program flow gets to that point in the source file.  It's as though you put `our $octate1;` at the top of the file, and `$octate1=0;` later on in the file.

Answer (score 0):

We can't really answer your question, because your code isn't 77 lines long. Turning on `strict` and `warnings` would help too.

However can I suggest you're doing something a lot more complicated than you need to - if you're trying to generate a random hex string mac address:

```
print join ( ":", map { sprintf("%02X", int (rand(  256))-1) } (0..5) );
```

Or as you indicate needing a `00` prefix:

```
print join ( ":", "00", map { sprintf("%02X", int (rand(  256))-1) } (0..4) );
```

I'm not sure what your issue with `sprintf` is - it's the tool for the job - but if that doesn't work there's other options to convert (you might have to write your own 'dectohex' function:

```
sub dec2hex_str {
    my ($value) = @_;
    my @conv = ( 0 .. 9, "A" .. "F" );
    my $result = '';
    while ($value) {
        my $mod = $value % 16;
        $value -= $mod;
        $value /= 16;
        $result = $conv[$mod] . $result;
    }
    if ( length($result) < 2 ) {
        $result = "0" . $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```